# When i am testing app then it crashes by error java.lang.RuntimeException:

Tags: android, xml, material-design

In my application i had formatted my xml files and now i am putting material desing in my app so when i am running application then There is one problem coming which is like these when i am running app:-
at

```
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #49: You must supply a layout_height attribute.
            at android.content.res.TypedArray.getLayoutDimension(TypedArray.java:491)
            at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.setBaseAttributes(ViewGroup.java:5615)
            at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.<init>(ViewGroup.java:5756)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>(LinearLayout.java:1823)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:1735)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.generateLayoutParams(LinearLayout.java:58)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:748)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:256)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:109)
            at com.technotwit.newspaperwala.LoginDecision.WhoLogin.onCreate(WhoLogin.java:18)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My layout code is :-

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".WhoLogin">

    <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">>

                <Button
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:paddingTop="20dp"

                    android:background="@drawable/circle"
                    android:drawableTop="@mipmap/userprofileimg"

                    android:text="Teacher Login"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/Teacher" />

                <android.support.v4.widget.Space
                    android:layout_width="20dp"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    />
                <Button
                    android:layout_width="150dp"
                    android:layout_height="150dp"
                    android:paddingTop="20dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circle"
                    android:drawableTop="@mipmap/userprofileimg"

                    android:text="Coordinator Login"
                    android:textColor="#fff"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:id="@+id/Coordinator" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Please Choose Your Login Domain"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:textColor="#030405"
                android:textSize="20dp" />


        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and my activity code is :-

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


    import com.technotwit.newspaperwala.R;
    public class WhoLogin extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button teacherlogin,cordinatorlogin;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.wlogin);
            teacherlogin= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Teacher);
            cordinatorlogin= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Coordinator);
            teacherlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("who","teacher");
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });
            cordinatorlogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent i =new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("who","coordinator");
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });

        }
    }
```

At these point i am stucking .

Comment: Check your included layout whether it has layout height? That is the toolbar layout

Comment: post your toolbar xml

Comment: please check your toolbar.xml file you have not add height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for support but i had solved this problem by checking my xml layout with  and
 then i had edited my code and finally code had successfully completed

Answer (score 0):

**Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Binary XML file line #49: You must supply a layout_height attribute.**

This is your error. If this occurs when you click on one of those buttons, then the error is in your MainActivty layout file(activity_main.xml line #49). Add height attribute to the element for which it is missing.

Answer (score 0):

try this code
toolbar.xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/my_awesome_toolbar"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:id="@+id/titletool" 
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
  </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

your layout code is:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/rootview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"

                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"


                android:text="Teacher Login"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/Teacher" />

            <android.support.v4.widget.Space
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                />
            <Button
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="150dp"
                android:paddingTop="20dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"


                android:text="Coordinator Login"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/Coordinator" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Please Choose Your Login Domain"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:textColor="#030405"
            android:textSize="20dp" />


    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

it is run perfect.try this